# Are sup, inf, max, min correct for the set $\{\frac{x}{x+1}: x \in A\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A \subseteq (0, +\infty)$ be such that $\inf A=0$ and $A$ is NOT bounded from above. Find, if they exist, max, min, sup, inf of the set 
$$B=\bigg\{ \frac{x}{x+1}: x \in A \bigg\}.$$

I think that
$$\sup B = 1, \space\inf B = 0,\space \nexists \max B,\space \nexists \min B$$

but I am not sure if it is right. Could you help me?

Comment: What would happen if $A=\{2,1,\frac12,\frac14, \frac18,\ldots\}$?  Or if $A$ is the open interval $(0,2)$?

Comment: @Henry I got stuck now!!Could you give me a hint??

Comment: @Henry I just edited my post!!!A is NOT bounded from above!!!!

Comment: evinda: so try $A=\{\ldots ,8,4,2,1,\frac12,\frac14, \frac18,\ldots\}$ i.e. all powers of $2$, or $A = (0, +\infty)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your edit (the word *NOT*), your suggested answers look correct.

Clearly $0 \lt \frac{x}{x+1} \lt 1$ if $x$ is positive, and it approaches but does not achieve $0$ for very small $x$, and approaches but does not achieve $1$ for very large $x$

Comment: Great!!!Thank you very much!!!